# Transform OpenGL convention camera to OpenCV convention matrix

Tags: opencv, opengl, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I am given 4 camera extrinsic parameter matrices, and i wrote some code to display those cameras and their vector systems in 3D.

Here is the code:

```
def plot_cameras(views):
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.set_aspect('equal')
for name, view in views.items():
#for name, view in {'test_cam': 0}.items():
    m = view.cam.m
    #m = Camera.make_lookat_m(
    #            colvec([10, 10, 10]),
    #            colvec( [0,0,0] ),
    #            colvec([0, 0, -1])
    #            )
    r = m[:3, :3].copy()
    r_t = r.T
    t = m[:3, 3].copy()
    pos = -r_t.dot(t)
    x_cam, y_cam, z_cam = pos # Camera pose
    u = 100*r_t[:, 0]
    v = 100*r_t[:, 1]
    w = 100*r_t[:, 2] # Camera u,v,w vectors
    ax.text(x_cam, y_cam, z_cam, name)
    ax.plot3D(
            [x_cam, x_cam +  u[0]],
            [y_cam, y_cam +  u[1]],
            [z_cam, z_cam +  u[2]],
            color='red')
    ax.plot3D(
            [x_cam, x_cam +  v[0]],
            [y_cam, y_cam +  v[1]],
            [z_cam, z_cam +  v[2]],
            color='green')
    ax.plot3D(
            [x_cam, x_cam +  w[0]],
            [y_cam, y_cam +  w[1]],
            [z_cam, z_cam +  w[2]],
            color='blue')
    ax.plot3D(
            [0],
            [0],
            [0],
            color='red',
            marker='*'
            )
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
set_axes_equal(ax)
plt.show()
```

I have 4 cameras at 0, +-25 and +90 degrees of the target.

I am told that these cameras are in OpenCV convention but my function clearly shows they are in OpenGL convention (looking down negative z axis).

[image: Four cameras pointing at central target (red star)]

Am I properly decomposing the camera matrix and extracting the vectors?
If so, is there a way of transforming my OpenGL-style camera matrices into OpenCV-style?

Comment: Why can't you just flip the Z axis?

Comment: I can flip Z and Y axis to keep the handedness, however there is the K matrix, any idea how that has to be affected?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the camera model you want to end up with? The first OpenCV documentation page that Google gave me had a camera model without any K matrix. Why do you need to preserve handedness? What is your ultimate goal here?